# Tag-it jquery: get tags from the webserivce

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tag-it

i am trying to get the tag-it tags from a webservice, the problem is i can even get into the success , the alert never shows up, nor the error event.

```
    $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
    //availableTags: sampleTags,
    // This will make Tag-it submit a single form value, as a comma-delimited field.
    singleField: true,
    placeholderText: "Start typing your tags...",
    singleFieldNode: $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_hidTags'),
    availableTags: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "WServices/TypeService.asmx/getTags",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ para_Parent_Name: "tags" }),
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert(data);
                return data;
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("errer");
                debugger;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are returning valid JSON back.  I would take exactly what is being returned back (through FireBug/Development tools) and put it in http://jsonlint.com/ to see if it is valid.

I offer this as an answer because we had huge problems when we switched between major versions of jQuery.  All of our AJAX stuff broke.  We finally figured out it was the JSON being returned.  If it wasn't valid then jQuery would fail silently.

Hope that provides a possible start to finding the solution.